# Problem loading images from googleusercontent

Tags: keychain, firefox, certificate

Recently switched from Chrome to Firefox Quantum and noticed that images from `*.googleusercontent.com` aren't loading because "The connection used to fetch the resource was not secure"

[image: Images from lh3.googleusercontent.com not loading]

If I attempt to load the image directly, Firefox gives "Unable to connect" and checking site info it shows that the "Connection is not secure"

[image: Loading a single image also has same problem]

Tried to fix the problem in Firefox by restarting in Safe-Mode and also "Refresh Firefox", unfortunately problem still exists.

Safari has the same problem (insecure connection). Everything works fine in Chrome.

Version details

- Firefox: v65.0.1 (and previously v63.0.3)
- Safari: v12.0.2
- Chrome: v70.0.3538.110
- MacOS: Mojave v10.14.2

Comment: Hi - great example. Now that you know two things: 1. Different browsers check security differently 2. Different browsers ignore the system lookup and just go to the address they “know” is the correct one bypassing your DNS - is there still a question or should I edit this into yours? Please feel free to take these words in yours pyko - the hosts file nailed _why_ in my mind.

Comment: Interesting thought. I was assuming that the hosts file would impact all browsers, though if the browsers check security differently then that sounds like a plausible explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On whim, decided to check my `/etc/hosts` file and noticed I had the following entry: `127.0.0.1 googlehosted.l.googleusercontent.com`

After removing it, the images now load as expected.

Interesting that Chrome still worked despite that entry..

Comment: Curious why Chrome worked despite the entry in `/etc/hosts` ...happy to give bounty to whoever explains it!